# Simulator showing wrong input

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl

I have written a testbench for a program in verilog. The weird problem is the simulator is showing input completely different compared to the one I have provided as input. Thus the output is also affected. Why is this happening? I am testing the code in Xilinx. Here is the test bench

my input is 1010101
simulator is showing 0110101

```
module HamDecoderTop;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg rst;
reg [6:0] hword;

// Outputs
wire [3:0] data;


HammingDecoder uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .rst(rst), 
    .hword(hword), 
    .data(data)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 0;
    rst = 0;

    #1 rst =1;

    #10 hword = 1010101;


end

always
#2 clk=~clk;

endmodule
```

Here is what simulator is showing.

[image]

Comment: The output is fine. Clocking is toggling after every 2 unit and hword is taking value `10101` after 10 unit of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepend your hword literal value with a `7'b` if you want it to be interpreted as a seven bit binary. By default it's interpreted as a decimal value `1,010,101`, which when converted to binary, is `11110110100110110101`. The first 7 bits of this binary number is what you're seeing in the simulator.